# PostgreSQL. Is using random tag in dollar quoting without escaping input safe?

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-injection, query-performance

Is that safe to run such query without escaping input? Assume noone can guess the random string I generate.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = $long random tag$ THIS NOT ESCAPED $long random tag$
```

What drawbacks are? 
For example if the tag will change for each transaction, will it have performance penalties?

EDIT: Doing escaping correctly is also sometimes tricky - remember PHP `mysql_escape` and `mysql_real_escape` and sometimes can be fooled or just forgotten. Proposed approach can be automatic.

EDIT 2: 
Any ideas if that can be made on pure Postgres SQL? Remember that dollar quoting can be nested.

Comment: Sounds like [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) (if even that). In other words: You should better assume, that everybody can guess your random value precisely and properly sanitize the input instead.

Comment: Not just that. What if the not escaped text is `' = '23' or true or '23' = '` ?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: that won't matter as the outer "quotes" are different. By using a "random" dollar quote tag, anything can be embedded in the actual string without the string escaping being "terminated"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh yes... dollar quoting. Which I never use because I always use query parameterisation.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres doesn't cache ad-hoc SQL query plans; only if your host environment is using [prepare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) will the query plan be cached. But if `prepare` is used, then parameterisation is also being used so dollar quoting won't be necessary.

It follows, then, if you're not using `prepare` that each query will be parsed. In that case, you're probably best off accepting the 2 * (32 + 2) = 68 byte penalty and use UUIDs inside dollar quoting.

You could write code to generate a random short string -- eg `$a$` and test if that appears in the input, and loop making that string longer if it appears. But the cost of such code might exceed just generating a UUID and using that.

Answer (score 2):

UUIDs are pretty much guaranteed unique, so if you use a quality random UUID it's pretty-much guaranteed safe. A time-based UUID would be very risky.

So if your random generator is of cryptographic quality then you're safe. If it's not, be afraid!

The probability of a DOS attack (eg: drop table) succeeding is very low, a lightning strike on the server is more likely. An exfiltration attack (download a copy of your database) would need several key clashes, and so 
is for all intents and purposes impossible.

That said, this approach is perverse, will raise eyebrows, and will ultimately cost more (in convincing others then oneself) than doing it the approved way (eg: quote-doubling, or parameterised queries).

Comment: type 4 is random (edit)

Comment: Doing escaping correctly is also tricky - like PHP mysql_escape and mysql_real_escape and sometimes can be fooled or just forgotten. Proposed approach can be made automatic.

Comment: now that postgres follows the SQL standard for stings escaping is very easy, just double all the quotes,